# Create font class in Android Studio and use it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want create fonts class and I use it

```
public class Fonts extends Activity{


public static Typeface typeface;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/dn.ttf");



}
```

}

and use it for example

```
      Typeface typeface = Fonts.typeface;

    Button btn_open = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_open);
    btn_open.setTypeface(typeface);
```

but it dosen't change !

in manifests.xml Fonts.java is launcher activity

What do I do ?
Thanks

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-customize-android-fonts--mobile-1601 check it out here

Comment: it is not i want create font class !

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are hiding your static variable declaring it again in your `onCreate()` method.
You need to remove the declaration:

```
public class Fonts extends Activity {
    public static Typeface typeface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Remove the "Typeface" declaration.
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/dn.ttf");
    }
}
```

**Personal advice**: avoid using a static variable to access to your `Typeface`.
Create a method in which you pass the `Context` from outside to get the `Typeface` or initialize it in your `Application` for example.